# Can I control how smooth handles the handlebar of a segment?

Tags: paperjs

I'm working with Paper.js for the first time now and I'm working on a yellow cube with fluid/waving sides. What I want is the side of a cube wave like this:

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/#animating-path-segments

But I want the corners of the cube to be fixed. I'm almost getting there but I walk into one problem segment[1](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) (topleft corner is [0]) is behaving strange. The handles are diagonal and not horizontal like the others.

[image]

How can I fix this?

My current sketch can be found [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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).

The full code is

```
var values = {
    margin: 64,
    header: 132,
    height: 60,
    amount: 5
};

 var path, springs;

function createPath(strength) {
    var size = view.size;

    var blockSize = {
        width: size.width - values.margin,
        height: size.height - values.header,
        segmentX: (size.width - values.margin)/(values.amount + 1),
        segmentY: (size.height - values.header)/(values.amount + 1)
    };

    var blockPosition = {
        top: size.height - blockSize.height,
        left: 0
    }

    var path = new Path({
        fillColor: 'yellow'
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= values.amount; i++) {
        //top
        path.add(new Point((blockPosition.left + (blockSize.segmentX * i)), blockPosition.top));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= values.amount; i++) {
        //left
        path.add(new Point(blockSize.width, blockPosition.top + (blockSize.segmentY * i)));
    }

    path.add(new Point(blockSize.width, blockSize.height + blockPosition.top));
    path.add(new Point(blockPosition.left, blockSize.height + blockPosition.top));


    path.fullySelected = true;
    path.closed = true;
    return path;
}

function onResize() {
    if (path)
        path.remove();
    path = createPath();
}

function onFrame(event) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= values.amount - 1; i++) {
        var segmentTop = path.segments[i];
        var segmentRight = path.segments[i + values.amount + 1];

        // A cylic value between -1 and 1
        var sinus = Math.sin(event.time * 3 + i);

        // Change the y position of the segment point:
        segmentTop.point.y = sinus * values.height + 100;
       // segmentRight.point.x = sinus * 1;

        path.smooth();
    }

    path.segments[0].handleIn.x = 0;
    path.segments[0].handleIn.y = 100;
    path.segments[0].handleOut.x = 100;
    path.segments[0].handleOut.y = 0;

    path.segments[6].handleIn.x = -100;
    path.segments[6].handleIn.y = 0;
    path.segments[6].handleOut.x = 0;
    path.segments[6].handleOut.y = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is due to the fact that you are applying the smoothing algorithm on the whole square, including corners.
So if you take a screenshot before setting corners handles to be horizontal/vertical, you see this:
[image]
I think that explain quite clearly why your second segment has a diagonal handle, this is because the previous segment has one too...

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating an effect similar to what you are trying to achieve.

```
// Define constants.
const POINTS_AMOUNT = 7;
const SQUARE_WIDTH = 500;
const WAVE_AMPLITUDE = 25;
const SQUARE_OFFSET = new Point(100, 100);

// Initialize path variable, we will use this reference to delete the previous
// path on each frame.
let path;

function draw(time) {
    // Delete existing path.
    if (path) {
        path.remove();
    }

    // Create new path.
    path = new Path();
    // First, draw the top side.
    for (let i = 0; i < POINTS_AMOUNT; i++) {
        // For each point of the line, create a wave effect by using sine
        // function. Do not apply it on first and last point to make square
        // corners stay constant.
        const sinus = i === 0 || i === POINTS_AMOUNT - 1
            ? 0
            : Math.sin(time * 3 + i);
        const x = SQUARE_WIDTH / POINTS_AMOUNT * i;
        const y = sinus * WAVE_AMPLITUDE;
        path.add(new Point(x, y));
    }
    // Apply smoothing algorithm on the line.
    path.smooth();

    // Duplicate this line 3 times to form a square.
    const right = path.clone().rotate(-90, path.lastSegment.point);
    right.reverse();
    const bottom = right.clone().rotate(-90, right.lastSegment.point);
    bottom.reverse();
    const left = bottom.clone().rotate(-90, bottom.lastSegment.point);

    // Join all parts together.
    path.join(right).join(bottom).join(left);
    path.closed = true;

    // Place the square somewhere we can see it.
    path.translate(SQUARE_OFFSET);

    // Stylize the square.
    path.fullySelected = true;
    path.fillColor = 'yellow';
}

function onFrame(event) {
    draw(event.time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what I needed to get my project to the next step.